# How fast do four Tire-Propellers have to rotate to lift 2000 lbs?

Tags: propeller, lift, aircraft-physics, propulsion, vtol

I just saw [this come out](https://www.avweb.com/avwebflash/news/Goodyear-Introduces-Tire-Propeller-Concept-232378-1.html), Goodyear's *Tire-Propeller Concept* – a combination tire that can also act as propeller (well, more like a ducted fan I guess).

There's a neat video that goes with it, describing how the fan blades need to bend while being used as a tire. (Otherwise, one winter in New England would take them out!)

Any ideas how fast something with say four 18 inch diameter wheel/propellers, and 3-4 inch fan blades, would have to spin to generate enough downforce to actually get 2000 pounds off the ground?

The weight is the vehicle with 4 motors, 300 pounds of batteries, 600 pounds of passengers & baggage; comparable to my 2500 lb max gross weight airplane, but with weight savings of no wings or tail structure, and batteries vs fuel. 4 motor/fans, and allowing (requiring?) the lift off process to be from a stop, so that all 4 motor/fans could be rotated from road use to propeller use (vs rolling on 2 like the video shows). I imagine 14,000 RPM or some high speed would make quite a lot of noise, compared to the takeoff noise of my 180 horse power engine and 86 inch propeller.

Edit: This rim-driven propeller wheel doesn't look like it would have much total blade are for moving air. That would take even more speed, wouldn't it? 
[image]

The [Moller Skycar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shlZySkGq6g) seemed quite noisy for a comparison.

Comment: Your going to get supersonic tip somewhere around 13500RPM which would be limiting for a rubber propeller

Comment: Got to imagine that would be pretty irritating to listen to if nearby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a back-of-the-envelope estimate. As a simplifying assumption, assume that a propeller generates lift by accelerating air through an opening of a particular size, at one particular speed. The formula for the amount of lift generated in this case is:

$$\text{Lift} = \text{Opening area} \cdot \text{Air density} \cdot \text{Exhaust speed}^2$$

For each propeller, the needed lift is 500 pounds force, and the area of each opening is $\pi \cdot (\text{$9$ inches})^2$.

So we can calculate the needed exhaust speed using Wolfram Alpha: [square root of (500 pounds force / (density of air * pi * (9 inches)^2))](https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=square+root+of+%28500+pounds+force+%2F+%28density+of+air+*+pi+*+%289+inches%29%5E2%29%29+)

The answer comes out to 230 mph. That's the speed that the air has to move downward through the rotors. I don't know how fast the propeller will have to move in order to make this happen, but it will be a comparable speed.

The amount of *power* required can be found by multiplying this number again by the amount of lift. According to Wolfram Alpha, that comes out to 307 horsepower (229 kilowatts) *per rotor*. So about 1,200 horsepower for the entire aircraft, *if the rotors were 100% efficient*.

Good luck with that.

Comment: 1,200 HP ~ 1 PT6A turbine engine, so it seems in the neighborhood of reasonable. The AW609 tiltrotor's got 3,880 HP total.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem reasonable to achieve with the simulations shown in the video, especially as one gets the impression the tires are being rotated from the rim using a magnetic repulsion kind of idea. Or maybe that was just the bearings, to allow high speed revolutions. Gotta get braking in there too somehow for road use.

Comment: The Williams FJ33 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_FJ33 used on the Cirrus jet FJ50 "produces between 1,000 lbf (4,400 N) and 1,800 lbf (8,000 N) static thrust", so is it correct to say one would need 2 of those to make 2000 pounds force to count the 2000 pound weight of the vehicle including 600 pounds for the motors themselves?  The separate quad copter/road wheels sounds more feasible.